# How scalable is mySQL server?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, scalability

I am debating on whether I should have three separate wordpress installs with three separate databases, or whether it would be okay to use multisite (which only uses one central db).

I am concerned that after having my site (blog, photo portfolio, development forum) up for a few years it will start to lag (since mySQL is supposedly not that scalable).

Is this a concern at all? Or should I just go to with multisite?

Comment: "mySQL is supposedly not that scalable" says who?

Comment: Your scalability problems are Wordpress - not mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am debating on whether I should have three separate wordpress installs with three separate databases, or whether it would be okay to use multisite

In the case of Wordpress I doubt you would see any serious difference in database performance between either setup.  A wordpress multisite setup creates separate tables for each blog.  There are only a few shared tables, and those mostly have to do with user accounts, and supporting the network.  The difference between a separate table in the same database, and a separate table in a different database is almost certainly minuscule.

It should be easier to maintain a single instance of Wordpress, and easier to keep it updated.  This should almost certainly be a bigger concern.